# Getting error that rake is missing despite the fact that it's there

Tags: ruby, rake

```
$ sudo ./msfconsole 
Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources 
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. 
$ rake --version 
rake, version 10.1.0
```

Does anyone know what could cause this?

I tried running bundle install, but when I try to run msfconsole again afterwards it throws the error again.

Comment: without sudo, I get all kinds of errors.. "psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected whitespace or line break while scanning a tag at line 5 column 14 (Psych::SyntaxError)"

Comment: This all begs the question of whether you actually want to run an exploit library as root, though. :-P

Answer (score 0):

It might be a PATH-related issue.

Try it with `sudo -E`, so that your PATH, gem locations, etc. all become available when running sudo.

Other possibilities might be detailed in these related questions:

- [Could not find rake with bundle exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978002/could-not-find-rake-with-bundle-exec)
- [bundle exec fails with "could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284914/bundle-exec-fails-with-could-not-find-rake-10-1-0-in-any-of-the-sources)
- [Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448526/could-not-find-rake-10-1-0-in-any-of-the-sources)

Comment: sudo -E gives the same errors that running without sudo does. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Well, that definitely means there's a PATH issue. Which answers the question you asked about. But you're still left needing to fix some incorrect yaml somewhere to make psych happy either way. (Suggestion, btw: debug this without sudo.) Methinks open a new question for that one, with the offending yaml that is getting parsed.